# A secure connection with an application and a dedicated server

Tags: encryption, vpn, webserver, internet, secure-coding

I'm wondering if this kind of technology is already exist (not VPN), I'm looking for a method to make secure internet connection within a dedicated server, where my laptop has a desktop application to encrypt and decrypt the data before sending or receiving it and the server has an application to do the same. Please check the attached illu for more details.Thanks[image]

Comment: Isnt this just https and a proxy?

Comment: stunnel, SSH port forwarding, using socat with OPENSSL\* parameters, HTTPS to a proxy, ... And what has the `secure-coding` tag to do with this question?

Answer (score 1):

I know of at least one technology that does what you are wanting: [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org)

stunnel is a secure proxy that uses public key cryptography. A typical use case scenario is securing a http web service. This is done by running the proxy on port 443 to receive and send secure messages, and directing the unencrypted traffic to the http web service, which is running on port 80. Port 443 is then exposed to external networks, while port 80 is restricted access so that only connections from the local machine are allowed.

stunnel can be configured as both a server and a client, which as I understand is the solution you are looking for.

Disclaimer: I haven’t used it before, I recommend  doing your own research before relying upon it.